# Check whether a regular expression is correct

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I'm given a description of a regular language $L$, and I have a candidate regular expression $R$.  Is there a systematic, step-by-step way to test whether the candidate regular expression is correct?

I know that there can be multiple regular expressions that are correct.

<sup>This is intended as a reference we can point others to. Please explain your method in a form that someone new  can understand it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It depends how the regular language $L$ is specified.  I describe below an algorithm for this problem, i.e., a systematic procedure that you can follow to check correctness.  You can simulate running such an algorithm by hand, with pencil-and-paper, if necessary: it might be tedious, but it works.  Even better yet, you can implement it on a computer and let the computer run the algorithm.

## As a finite automaton

If the language $L$ is provided in the form of a finite automaton (e.g., DFA or NFA), then there are standard algorithms to check whether the NFA/DFA is equivalent to $L$, i.e., whether they generate the same language.

1. If you have a NFA for $L$, first convert it to a DFA for $L$ (e.g., using the [subset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction)).  If it is already a DFA, you can skip this step.
2. Then, convert the regular expression $R$ to a NFA (e.g., using [Thompson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction), or [using Brzozowski derivatives](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/136042/755)) and convert the NFA to a DFA.  Or, you can see https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13606/755 for details on how to convert a regular expression to a DFA.
3. Minimize both DFA (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization).
4. Finally, check whether the two minimal DFA are isomorphic, i.e., are the same, after relabelling of states.  If they are the same, then the regular expression $R$ is correct.  If they are not the same, then the regular expression is incorrect -- and moreover, you can identify a specific word that is accepted by one DFA and not by the other, and thus which demonstrates that $R$ is not a correct regular expression.

See also [How do I verify that a DFA is equivalent to a NFA?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50505/755), as well as [Is there a way to test if two NFAs accept the same language?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12624/755) if you are implementing this in practice.

## As a regular expression

If $L$ is described by providing a regular expression, then test whether the two regular expressions are equivalent.  See [Algorithm to determine whether two regexes are equivalent](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12267/755) for a detailed description of how to do that.  (Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/52860/755.)

## Provided in some other way

If the language $L$ is specified in some other way, you can first find a finite automaton for it (see [How to prove a language is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755)) or find a regular expression for it (see [How do I find a regular expression for a particular language?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45570/755)), then apply the above methods.

## Other approaches

There are other methods as well.  See, e.g., [Proving Equivalence of Two Regular Expressions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150895/755) for description of other methods that might be easier in some circumstances.